# Quel est le plus long palindrome de la langue française ?

Tags: france

Quel est le plus long palindrome de la langue française ?

Et question annexe: quelle est la plus longue phrase palindrome ?

Answer (score 3):

Le plus long mot : ressasser (9 caractères

La plus longue phrase : Et si l'arôme des bottes révèle madame, le verset t'obsède, moraliste ! (Alain Damasio, 11 mots et 59 caractères espaces non compris)

Le plus long texte : Pol Kools aurait fait mieux que George Perec et ses 1247 mots, avec le palindrome de St Gille qui fait 2119 mots (9331 caractères espaces non compris) :

> Parti du relégitimé, l’émoi d’illettrés se dénudera de radotages. Ave
> Maria, jumelage codétenu à ton essor, Genet idéaliserait sa lèvre. Ce
> dégât, râpé de mer, accosté – par après, il a viré – te roda l’optimal
> listage, le Civil. Ô joie au Y et s’il en use, utérus, salut à toi,
> nudiste et si l’Audiard ne t’éjecte, récuse ton urbanité – ipséité, ça
> fédère mal. Hanoi t’a régi, brevet love-rival. Euh, ce départ t’a
> ralenti ? Ô crâne dégarni, magnifique félicité, use du rap aliéné.
> Bat-on ce sergent rom, aussi l’amer réaliste, sexe vêtu ? T’es sec, ce
> méga taré, même las, Lee, tu as limé. Elle berce Melun et erre. Mal
> raplati, redémarre, il bat la mesure-Lido d’Évian et t’éclopera
> godasse, révolte. Cornet pur, banal remède, l’aromate écarte, redouté.
>
> Vice-versa, sus au qat, t’autonomise-t-il à ta façon, notable érudit,
> nanar, été acté en recueil ? Elle va, racolage, ne s’épate-t-elle pas,
> réversibilité, souverain et ami, l’Auvergnate ? Le désaveu qu’on imite
> baisse, utile gnaule, verve, il engagera l’acariâtre Pol à Geu. Que
> valider : crème, lard, repli ? Viva le taxi, dorez-en ! I am, ha, tu
> es, il a ! « Général camisard » répète le taliban râblé. Si, mate ça,
> la prise de tête : mitigé, le Dalaï-Lama se résigna, yeti. Nul ne se
> dira San-A ! Nase barasta-rime, secrets, étalages ineptes, sabir
> attesté jeunet, elle t’atténua. Tu avales Laval, si, Aerton Senna, tu
> traces sur Évère, j’avise, tape-cul alien, éloges à ton art,
> amuse-toi, pèlerin esseulé. Et toc, samedi protège, il a l’âge. Ce
> Sergi, amer, déçu de ta dot puérile, a cassé l’pot. Ne rime guêpes.
> Œdème rêche not to L.A. from Nice de mec à saper. Tout sang ocré,
> félidé italien, à perte le fric. Rions et s’il se – délit ! – nacre
> mal, lit avec rage, sou trivial, éjacule dur, balanite made in orifice
> rénal, pore, aérage ! Et parle ! L’Eden m’a durci, drame canin en
> réclame. Les opiacés rapportés, il a rompu. Calcul net abyssal, tapote
> ça et rue. Hexaèdre me dératise, rage dialectale me déride l’issue
> utérine.
>
> Ebay a périclité : sûre Mustang américaine B. lucrative, kimono,
> bikini, drap, carats, diam, rabe d’un tarot, céleri-Melba. Malbâti,
> bronzé, Pol le basané radine. Ce dada redore. Palâtre se dédise
> l’aisselle. Rémi altère le but. Super été, le dégazage de soute flaira
> ton cas. Si, Matelot, elle m’a, gasoil-plage, elle terra. Je
> tropicalise Râ l’Odéon, elle m’a mérité. Le bec tente ces litres en
> Isère et Cali-Medellin avec algèbre. Hasard amarré sur ce léger regel,
> as, arc émergé né du ressac, artiste tel Perec, arase le mal ce soir
> et s’il a l’zéro féru, le fera-t-il, ce bac à mot sexuel, lire par
> Eric ? Anissa commue l’Opus Dei, pas une vers toi. Diego de la Véga,
> vil, cibla au rapport : E.L.F., F.I.S, sale H.I.V. Renégats ou
> décédés, sera-ce nullité ? Me scrute-t-il en observant nos sens ? Et
> si Rita sert au Q.G., agneau, Messire, était Raps Alain. Le « ah »
> parte en notes, en sol et ré, la.
>
> Le café, ça freine, si l’âne peine, gelons ionisés. Ne plie pas, Noé,
> le papelard n’axe là. Autre mire, périmètre, nielle, erreurs. Reverse
> le brut réparé pour si peu qu’on – insère-t-il l’autel bâti ? –
> m’initiât. Écrase ce valet, tu l’as nui. Cinéma, sidérale javeline,
> brio, sel et appareil pare-feu. Par telle ruse d’ici, Mohammed
> n’amortit – épistèmê non-ratifiable, icône née d’Islam – no Tanger,
> not Alger … Ria, le minaret : Emir, révèle ta gêne, récit, sujet nié,
> recrute la sueur. Néolocal animalier à Pau, Gardel le mac – essor ?
> galère ? – mat en rut – con ? – M.T.V. pocket size. Par tel zélateur
> ébarbez-le ! Crame, vil Nestor ! Là, naturel, semer ce désir perdu.
> Ah, ça suffit. Ah, ces totems ! Agronome doré, avenue. Jamais reçu à
> Xérès : sel, baril à paroles, rêve de jadis. Elle me fera gicler
> bâclage, rudesse raciste, elle me fera mal à crever. Ca turbule, exil
> orphelin, remèdes.
>
> Servile en toi, farcis une urne. Le P.S. – dogme ni menotté, ni
> névrosé, R.T.T. – se ligature. Brel a géré le trac établi. Zen, Ame,
> Loi, Vertu. Entubé de désir, ce vil aselle se vida. La méga-rétro
> alerte tue. Parer, reset, reçu sténo secret. Curé Sorel semi-autiste,
> juste. Mondial I.T.T., on émet Télé-Morue, trop ! Parti du R.E.R, on
> étripa. Tel le magnéto, le con ignore si le laser U.V. rendra déridé.
> Lupanar, asile, harem, I am not avec Ami Lévi, consul Perès. Il
> entérine : Vade retro mâle, été fatal ! Cette étagère fit sept
> sesterces.
>
> Yvan, à la fin, a mal amianté, il n’a laissé là, demi-bas, ni le velu
> outsider, ni l’écrevisse licite. Oh, ce laid arrêt … Epave tsigane,
> mate ça, le genre. Va, Camel, bat ce Jésus paludéen. Une maxime, le
> rite sévit, camelot. Si Farid, nul n’a vidé ce lit, unité égarée,
> bave, sue, mercenaire, lavette, cérumen ! Il a clamé, titres niais en
> main, or à camelot, édite Feria Nîmes. Tralala éditeur de Rio t’a lu
> ça ? J’en ai demain. Usuel, cossu, Colbleu te prépare. Pol, no time.
> Drapé du titre « ça, le si mini », Metro-Media relate, le ça frustré
> se délite, ranime le tissu érogène. Suce-sedergine. Djerba, la photo,
> la fête, la noce, la mémé : séniles.
>
> Avide juderia, nul n’a lésiné, déicide Mahomet, idem. Mami l’écartela,
> donc il céda. Tu obéis. Porc, Amiral inapte, Toni Martel le Bernois
> accosta. Bec évasé, le tube d’ici gerba. Banni, Ali vise le GI. Si
> Omar y trame l’aridité, Setim renomme la Sûre. J’ai bu, aber à morues.
> Sape le tir bas à pet né de l’enfer, bête à lier, ovin morose. Verset
> relu, ce rebut né de rut nié cala. Et tu l’as averti. Le bazar, air à
> la masse, part. Asservi et l’axe rusé, j’actai par l’âne. Vise le top
> à ce jeu. Trèves – il a peu lavé – dodues. Prise d’otage. Déni,
> brutalité. Eh ça, ça se réalisa, Père ? L’agent éclaté du GIA élucide
> ? Fi, terni, tu l’arrêtes ? Et, Si Raza l’islamiste nia la rue, tua
> l’auteur Alain ? Et si mal, si lazariste, se terra, lutin rétif.
> Edicule aigu de talc. Et ne galère pas, il aère sa cache et il a
> turbiné.
>
> Dégât, ô désir pseudo-dévalué, pâli, s’évertue, je capote. Le si vénal
> rapiat. ça, je surexalte, ivres satrapes, sa malaria. Raza, belître,
> va, sa lutte à la ceinture d’entubé reculer tes rêves. Or, omnivore,
> il a été bref. Ne l’édente pas, abrite le passeur Omar ébaubi. A
> Jérusalem, mon ermite Seti dira : le martyr a moisi, gelé, si vilain.
> Nabab régicide, bute-les avec ébats. Occasion rebelle, traminot, et
> pan! Il a ri. Macropsie, boutade, clic, nodale trace. L’Imam médite,
> Mohamed ici édenise l’an lunaire du jedi vaseliné. Sème ma leçon à
> l’été falot. Oh, palabre, j’dénigre des écus en ego, réussite. Le
> minaret, île, désert, surface létale raide morte, minimise la
> certitude par demi-ton. L’opéra perpétuel, blocus, socle U.S. uni à
> médiane jaculatoire, dru et idéal à l’art, séminaire fétide, tôle,
> macaroni. Amnesia insert item. Alcaline mûre, cette valériane crémeuse
> va béer. Agé et inutile, ce divan lundi rafistolé m’active, s’étire,
> le mixa menu. Née du lapsus éjectable, ma caverne gela, cet aménagiste
> va péter, radial écho. Et ici lessiver ce lin. Redis-tu où le vélin
> s’abîme, D’Alès ? Si … Alan Li et Naïma, la manif à la Navy. Secret
> s’est pestiféré, gâté et t’éclata. Fêtée, la mort, ère d’avenir…et ne
> lisère plus, nocive limace !
>
> Va-t-on m’aimer ? Ah, Eli, Sara n’a pu le dire. Dard, nervure, sale
> liseron, gin, ocelot en gamelle, tapir, ténor, érudit, rapporteur,
> omelette, Menotti, laid nom, et sujet. Si tu aimes l’Eros, éructer ce
> son et sucer te serrera peut-être l’aorte. Rage maladive, selle,
> salive, crise de début neutre, viol, émanez ! Il bat. Écarteler,
> égaler Béru-tag ? Il est trésor, venin … et ton Eminem, Godspel en rue
> nu (Sic). Rafiot, née l’ivresse de mer, Nil, eh prolixe élu brut, âcre
> ver, calamare femelle. Et si …Caresse du régal, Cabrel, cigare,
> femelle,… Sida, je déverse l’or à pâlir, à blesser, exaucer. Siam, à
> jeun, Eva érode mon orgasme tôt. Sec, hâtif, fusa chaud. Reprise de
> crèmes le rut anal. Rots en live, Marcel zébra Béru. Étalez le
> trapéziste K.C. op V.T.M. Nocturne, ta mère, la grosse Camel, le
> dragua pareil à Mina. La colo en rue usa le turc éreinté.
>
> Justice renégate, lever rime, te ranime l’air. Régla-t-on ? Régna-ton
> ? « Mal sidéen en O, ciel bai » fit Arno. N’émet si petit roman
> d’Emma, « Homicide sur elle trapue ». Fer à plier appâté. Le soir béni
> leva. Je la redis ? Amen. Ici, un salut tel « ave César », c’était
> inimitable. Tu allitéres « Ninouque Pis ». Ru opéra perturbe les
> revers. Ruer, réelle, inerte mire, périmer tua Alexandra. Le pape Léon
> sapé, il pense, si « no is no », le génie pénalise, nier face-face
> l’alerte. L’os ne s’étonne et Raphaël nia la Spartiate. Eris se mua en
> gag. Quatre satiristes nés sont navrés, bon. Élite, turc, sème-t-il ?
> Lune, caresse de ce duo, stage nervi hélas sifflé, trop paru. A
> Albi-clivage, va le doge. Idiots revenus à pied. Sup oléum mocassin à
> cirer à périlleux estomac à bec, lit à refêlure, forez la listériose !
> clame-le, Sara ! Ce replet et si tracassé rude nègre m’écrasa. Léger
> regel écru serra madras à herbe, glace vanille demi-lactée, résine.
> Sert-il, sec et net, ce bel étire-mamelle, Noé ? Do, la ré, si, la,
> ci, porte-jarretelle égal pli. Os à gamelle, tôle, tamis, sac
> notarial, fétu osé, dégazage délétère, pus-tu bêler et l’aimer ?
> Elles, si ! Alési de désert, à l’apéro, dérada de ce nid, Arenas Abel
> Lopez n’orbita, blâmable mire.
>
> Lectorat nu de barmaid ? Starac, pardi : Niki, Bono, Mike Vitar
> cul-béni à cire, magnats, umérus… Et il cire pAya.be. En ire, tu eus
> si le dire démêlât ce lai de gare si taré de merde. Axe heurté à ce
> top, Atlas s’y bat en Luc, la Cup moralise trop, parsec. Ai posé le
> mal cerné, Nina, ce mardi cru. Damned, Elel rapte, égare aéroplane,
> récif, ironie. Dame Tina, la bru de Luca, je l’ai, virtuose garce.
> Va-t-il, là mercantile, des listes noircir ? Fêlé, trépané, il a tiédi
> le fer. Cognas-tu, ô trépas, à ce médecin morfal, Otton ? Eh, ce
> remède ose peu gémir en topless à ça. Élire ? Up to date, du cèdre
> maigre sec égal à Liège, torpide mascotte élue S.S. en ire.
>
> « Lépiote, Sumatra » nota Ségolène, il a lu ce patési. Va, je rêve
> russe car tu tannes notre ais. La valse la vaut au net. T’a-t-elle,
> ténue jet-set, tari ? Basset, pénis égal à tester ces émirats arabes à
> nanas arides ? En l’unité Yang is Ères , Amalia l’a délégitimé. Tête
> de sir Palace t’a mis El Barnabi. La télé te perdra si Mac Laren
> égalise ! Utah-Maine : zéro – dix à Tel-Aviv. Il perdra le mercredi.
> L’aveu que galoper taira ça, la regagne. Lièvre velu, Angéli, tu es si
> abêti, Minou, que vase de l’étang revu à Lima ! Ténia revu, ose-t-il,
> ibis, rêver ? Sa pelle te tape, Sénégal, ô Caravelle, lieu cerné et
> caetera … Nanti du réel bât, on noça, fatalité ? Si, Mono, tu
> attaquas, usas, rêve ci-vêtu, ode retracée, ta morale de merlan abrupt
> en roc et lover-ès-sado. Gare Pol, cette naïve d’Odile ruse mal.
> Tablier, rame de rital. Par la mer retenu, le mec rebelle, Émil, saute
> Elsa, le même ratage, mec ! Cesse, tu te vexes.
>
> Et s’il a erré, mal issu, à mort nègre sec, nota bene, il a paru
> désuet. Ici, le feu – Q.I., fin gamin, rage de narcoït – ne la
> rattrape déchue, la virevolte – verbigération, ah… La mère de facéties
> piétina Bruno. Te sucer … et ce, je tendrai. Dualiste et si… d’un
> iota, tu l’as ! Sûre, tu es une liste : Y.U.A.E.I.O… Joli, vice-légat,
> s’il la mit, Pol adore te rivaliser : parapet, soc, carême de partage
> de cervelas, tiare. S’il a édité, « Negros » se nota un été d’Oc,
> égal, ému, j’ai ramé, va … Segato, dare-dare, d’une, dessert tel
> l’idiome, le mitigé, l’érudit rap …

sources : wiikipedia et jeretiens.net

Comment: Merci ! J'essaye de le décrypter mais ce n'est pas chose aisée.

Comment: bon courage ! Ecrire ce texte fut une prouesse, mais lui donner du sens en est une autre.

Answer (score 2):

***Ressasser*** et <s>***Engage le jeu que je le gagne***</s> sont apparemment les plus longs connus.

Comment: Oui `ressasser` est connu ! Pourquoi avoir supprimer le second ?

Comment: Parce que je me suis dit que ce n'était pas le plus long, ce qui a été confirmé plus tard avec la réponse de radouxju.

Comment: D'accord. Merci

Answer (score 2):

En ce qui concerne le plus long texte palindrome, [cette source](https://jeretiens.net/palindrome-de-georges-perec-au-moulin-dande/) l'attribue à Georges Perec avec un essai de 1247 mots, « Au moulin d’Andé » écrit en 1969.

Le palindrome de Georges Perec

> Trace l’inégal palindrome. Neige. Bagatelle, dira Hercule. Le brut repentir, cet écrit né Perec. L’arc lu pèse trop, lis à vice versa. Perte. Cerise d’une vérité banale, le Malstrom, Alep, mort édulcoré, crêpe porté de ce désir brisé d’un iota. Livre si aboli, tes sacres ont éreinté, cor cruel, nos albatros. Être las, autel bâti, miette vice versa du jeu que fit, nacré, médical, le sélénite relaps, ellipsoïdal. Ivre il bat, la turbine bat, l’isolé me ravale : le verre si obéi du Pernod — eh, port su ! – obsédante sonate teintée d’ivresse. Ce rêve se mit — peste ! — à blaguer. Beh ! L’art sec n’a si peu qu’algèbre s’élabore de l’or évalué. Idiome étiré, hésite, bâtard replié, l’os nu. Si, à la gêne secrète — verbe nul à l’instar de cinq occis –, rets amincis, drailles inégales, il, avatar espacé, caresse ce noir Belzebuth, œil offensé, tire ! L’écho fit (à désert) : Salut, sang, robe et été. Fièvres. Adam, rauque ; il écrit : Abrupt ogre, eh, cercueil, l’avenir tu, effilé, génial à la rue (murmure sud eu ne tire vaseline séparée ; l’épeire gelée rode : Hep, mortel ?) lia ta balafre native. Litige. Regagner (et ne m’…). Ressac. Il frémit, se sape, na ! Eh, cavale ! Timide, il nia ce sursaut. Hasard repu, tel, le magicien à morte me lit. Un ignare le rapsode, lacs ému, mixa, mêla : Hep, Oceano Nox, ô, béchamel azur ! Éjaculer ! Topaze ! Le cèdre, malabar faible, Arsinoë le macule, mante ivre, glauque, pis, l’air atone (sic). Art sournois : si, médicinale, l’autre glace (Melba ?) l’un ? N’alertai ni pollen (retêter : gercé, repu, denté…) ni tobacco. Tu, désir, brio rimé, eh, prolixe nécrophore, tu ferres l’avenir velu, ocre, cromant-né ? Rage, l’ara. Veuglaire. Sedan, tes elzévirs t’obsèdent. Romain ? Exact. Et Nemrod selle ses Samson ! Et nier téocalli ? Cave canem (car ce nu trop minois – rembuscade d’éruptives à babil — admonesta, fil accru, Têtebleu ! qu’Ariane évitât net. Attention, ébénier factice, ressorti du réel. Ci-gît. Alpaga, gnome, le héros se lamente, trompé, chocolat : ce laid totem, ord, nil aplati, rituel biscornu ; ce sacré bedeau (quel bât ce Jésus !). Palace piégé, Torpédo drue si à fellah tôt ne peut ni le Big à ruer bezef. L’eugéniste en rut consuma d’art son épi d’éolienne ici rot (eh… rut ?). Toi, d’idem gin, élèvera, élu, bifocal, l’ithos et notre pathos à la hauteur de sec salamalec ? Élucider. Ion éclaté : Elle ? Tenu. Etna but (item mal famé), degré vide, julep : macédoine d’axiomes, sac semé d’École, véniel, ah, le verbe enivré (ne sucer ni arrêter, eh ça jamais !) lu n’abolira le hasard ? Nu, ottoman à écho, l’art su, oh, tara zéro, belle Deborah, ô, sacre ! Pute, vertubleu, qualité si vertu à la part tarifé (décalitres ?) et nul n’a lu trop s’il séria de ce basilic Iseut. Il à prié bonzes, Samaritain, Tora, vilains monstres (idolâtre DNA en sus) rêvés, évaporés : Arbalète (bètes) en noce du Tell ivre-mort, émeri tu : O, trapu à elfe, il lie l’os, il lia jérémiade lucide. Pétard ! Rate ta reinette, bigleur cruel, non à ce lot ! Si, farcis-toi ito le cœur ! Lied à monstre velu, ange ni bête, sec à pseudo délire : Tsarine (sellée, là), Cid, Arétin, abruti de Ninive, Déjanire… Le Phénix, ève de sables, écarté, ne peut égarer racines radiales en mana : l’Oubli, fétiche en argile. Foudre. Prix : Ile de la Gorgone en roc, et, ô, Licorne écartelée, Sirène, rumb à bannir à ma (Red n’osa) niére de mimosa : Paysage d’Ourcq ocre sous ive d’écale ; Volcan. Roc : tarot célé du Père. Livres. Silène bavard, replié sur sa nullité (nu à je) belge : ipséité banale. L’ (eh, ça !) hydromel à ri, psaltérion. Errée Lorelei… Fi ! Marmelade déviré d’Aladine. D’or, Noël : crèche (l’an ici taverne gelée dès bol…) à santon givré, fi !, culé de l’âne vairon. Lapalisse élu, gnoses sans orgueil (écru, sale, sec). Saluts : angiome. T’es si crâneur ! * * * Rue. Narcisse ! Témoignas-tu ! l’ascèse, là, sur ce lieu gros, nasses ongulées… S’il a pal, noria vénale de Lucifer, vignot nasal (obsédée, le genre vaticinal), eh, Cercle, on rode, nid à la dérive, Dèdale (M… !) ramifié ? Le rôle erre, noir, et la spirale mord, y hache l’élan abêti : Espiègle (béjaune) Till : un as rusé. Il perdra. Va bene. Lis, servile repu d’électorat, cornac, Lovelace. De visu, oser ? Coq cru, ô, Degas, y’a pas, ô mime, de rein à sonder : à marin nabab, murène risée. Le trace en roc, ilote cornéen. O, grog, ale d’elixir perdu, ô, feligrane ! Eh, cité, fil bu ! ô ! l’anamnèse, lai d’arsenic, arrérage tué, pénétra ce sel-base de Vexin. Eh, pèlerin à (Je : devin inédit) urbanité radicale (elle s’en ira…), stérile, dodu. Espaces (été biné ? gnaule ?) verts. Nomade, il rue, ocelot. Idiot-sic rafistolé : canon ! Leur cruel gibet te niera, têtard raté, pédicule d’aimé rejailli. Soleil lie, fléau, partout ire (Métro, Mer, Ville…) tu déconnes. Été : bètel à brasero. Pavese versus Neandertal ! O, diserts noms ni à Livarot ni à Tir ! Amassez. N’obéir. Pali, tu es ici : lis abécédaires, lis portulan : l’un te sert-il ? à ce défi rattrapa l’autre ? Vise-t-il auquel but rêvé tu perças ? Oh, arobe d’ellébore, Zarathoustra ! L’ohcéan à mot (Toundra ? Sahel ?) à ri : Lob à nul si à ma jachère, terrain récusé, nervi, née brève l’haleine véloce de mes casse-moix à (Déni, ô !) décampé. Lu, je diverge de ma flamme titubante : une telle (étal, ce noir édicule cela mal) ascèse drue tua, ha, l’As. Oh, taper ! Tontes ! Oh, tillac, ô, fibule à rêve l’Énigme (d’idiot tu) rhétoricienne. Il, Œdipe, Nostradamus nocturne et, si né Guelfe, zébreur à Gibelin tué (pentothal ?), le faiseur d’ode protège. Ipéca… : lapsus. Eject à bleu qu’aède berça sec. Un roc si bleu ! Tir. ital. : palindrome tôt dialectal. Oc ? Oh, cep mort et né, mal essoré, hélé. Mon gag aplati gicle. Érudit rossérecit, ça freine, benoit, net. Ta tentative en air auquel bète, turc, califat se (nom d’Ali-Baba !) sévit, pure de — d’ac ? — submersion importune, crac, menace, vacilla, co-étreinte… Nos masses, elles dorment ? Etc… Axé ni à mort-né des bots. Rivez ! Les Etna de Serial-Guevara l’égarent. N’amorcer coulevrine. Valser. Refuter. Oh, porc en exil (Orphée), miroir brisé du toc cabotin et né du Perec : Regret éternel. L’opiniâtre. L’annulable. Mec, Alger tua l’élan ici démission. Ru ostracisé, notarial, si peu qu’Alger, Viêt-Nam (élu caméléon !), Israël, Biafra, bal à merde : celez, apôtre Luc à Jéruzalem, ah ce boxon ! On à écopé, ha, le maximum Escale d’os, pare le rang inutile. Métromane ici gamelle, tu perdras. Ah, tu as rusé ! Cain ! Lied imité la vache (à ne pas estimer) (flic assermenté, rengagé) régit. Il évita, nerf à la bataille trompé. Hé, dorée, l’Égérie pelée rape, sénile, sa vérité nue du sérum : rumeur à la laine, gel, if, feutrine, val, lieu-créche, ergot, pur, Bâtir ce lieu qu’Armada serve : if étété, éborgnas-tu l’astre sédatif ? Oh, célérités ! Nef ! Folie ! Oh, tubez ! Le brio ne cessera, ce cap sera ta valise ; l’âge : ni sel-liard (sic) ni master-(sic)-coq, ni cédrats, ni la lune brève. Tercé, sénégalais, un soleil perdra ta bétise héritée (Moi-Dieu, la vérole !) Déroba le serbe glauque, pis, ancestral, hébreu (Galba et Septime-Sévère). Cesser, vidé et nié. Tetanos. Etna dès boustrophédon répudié. Boiser. Révèle l’avare mélo, s’il t’a béni, brutal tablier vil. Adios. Pilles, pale rétine, le sel, l’acide mercanti. Feu que Judas rêve, civette imitable, tu as alerté, sort à blason, leur croc. Et nier et n’oser. Casse-t-il, ô, baiser vil ? à toi, nu désir brisé, décédé, trope percé, roc lu. Détrompe-la. Morts : l’Ame, l’Élan abêti, revenu. Désire ce trépas rêvé : Ci va ! S’il porte, sépulcral, ce repentir, cet écrit ne perturbe le lucre : Haridelle, ta gabegie ne mord ni la plage ni l’écart.

En savoir plus sur: https://jeretiens.net/palindrome-de-georges-perec-au-moulin-dande/

En savoir plus sur: https://jeretiens.net/palindrome-de-georges-perec-au-moulin-dande/